# Git: merge branch into parent, excluding parent->branch merges?

Tags: git, merge, cherry-pick

So, I've got a scenario that looks about like the following:

```
A----B----C----D (master)
 \    \    \
  E-F--G--H-I (child)
```

`C` and `D` in this case represents huge sets of changes, including lots of rearranging of directory trees.  `F` and `H` are much smaller, and generally limited to contents of files.  The individual files in `F` and `H` haven't changed much in `B`, `C`, or `D`.  All of these revisions exist in a shared upstream repository (so anything that edits history is out, as I understand it).

What's the easiest can I end up with a branch that contains `A, B, C, D, F`, and `H`?

Doing `git checkout master; git merge child` ends up reverting a large amount of the structural changes made in `C` and `D`, I'm assuming because it's picking up the changes from the merge commits `G` and `I`.  (Lots of the files that were relocated in `C` and `D` end up in the working tree twice.)

I can do a cherry-pick on `F` and `H` (though in my example, they represent about a dozen commits - enough to be annoying).

Ideally what I'd like would be a `git merge --ignore-merge-commits` option.

I don't think I can `rebase` child onto `D`, because `E-I` are all already in a shared repo.

Any other suggestions, or should I just go cherry picking?

Thanks!

Comment: This might be useful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25886147/git-rebase-skip-merge-commits/25894618#25894618

Comment: Try checking out a new branch from the head of 'child' and merging from master to your new branch. Then try a merge from the new branch back to master (or another local branch checked out from master)

Comment: @Jubobs - that's basically what I wound up doing; I was just wondering if there was a way to make "merge" be smarter about what it did.

Comment: @kdopen - that didn't help; I still wound up with a bunch of (outdated) changes from the merge commits G and I showing up in my merged baseline

Comment: Is this a public repo (on github or similar)? You said everything had been pushed upstream. being able to look at it would help

Comment: Alternatively, how many people share this repo? Rewriting history is painful, but if *everyone involved* knows it's going to happen and agrees, it can be managed. Finally, you can always use local rewriting to create a new branch which looks just right, push up that branch (with a distinct name) and when it's fully validated rename it to master (saving the old master with a different name). There's nothing special in git about that branch name :)

Comment: Nope, it's non-public.  Shared among a team of ~30.  Though your comment leads me to ask - could I do a local rewrite (e.g. with a rebase) and then push in a manner that the server doesn't see a rewrite, just a bunch of new revisions?