# Cherry Picking multiple commits

Tags: git, merge, atlassian-sourcetree, cherry-pick

We have recently migrated from SVN to GIT,our code is hosted on Atlassian Bitbucket and using Atlassian SourceTree as our desktop client.
Now we have a couple of projects with branches for our code base,ie. Integration branch for UAT and Release branch for Stage. The problem is that while migrating the code from UAT to Stage through SourceTree, we are using cherry pick for a huge number of commits and that is driving us insane.
Do we have an alternative for this tedious process in the source tree or do we have to write a script.
Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to cherry-pick multiple commits](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1670970/how-to-cherry-pick-multiple-commits)

Comment: Are you sure you don't want to `git merge` the branches rather than cherry-picking the commits?

Comment: Check out this answer here. I like the text file approach. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15687346/git-cherry-pick-range-of-commits-and-exclude-some-in-between